# Jquery- Bainding Ctr+t is not working in Chrome?

Tags: browser, jquery

I was trying to bind Ctrl+t with some event.. the code is...

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) { 
 if (event.ctrlKey && (event.which == 84)) {
 console.log('Ctrl+t was pressed');
    window.location.href ="www.example.com"; 
     return false;
}
  return true;//Pass the event on
```

});

it is working fine with Mozilla but, not in Crome . I am using current version of crome.

Comment: Try debugging using developer tools of Chrome. Put a breakpoint in your function to see if you get there.

Comment: I have tried , it fails if condition....

Comment: Look at event.which value then. Is it 84 ?

Comment: Ctrl-T is used to open a new tab... you shouldn't override a common shortcut like this.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=33056

Comment: I can override in any other browsers like mozilla/IE/Epic... and it works very fine... Why not in crome...? is there any way to do that in crome??

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome4 the browser executes the default action (i.e. open new window, 
open new tab and close tab/window) and does not execute the JavaScript 
intercept (at all).
In IE7, IE8, FF3, FF3.5 and Chrome3 the intercept works fine.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=33056